# PHP не принимает ajax

Tags: javascript, php

Всем здравствуйте)
Что имею:
Ссылка:

```
<a href="" title="" onclick="document.dir.folder.value = '<? echo $value?>'; 
listdir();"><?php echo $value; ?></a>
```

JS:

```
function listdir(){
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open('POST', 'App.php', true);
xhttp.send("folder="+document.getElementById('folder').value);
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhttp.readyState != 4) {
    return;
}
    if (xhttp.status == 200) {
        console.log(xhttp.responseText);
    }else{
        console.log(xhttp.responseText);
}
}
}
```

При клике на ссылку заполняется скрытое от user'a поле folder и передаётся js. Всё передаётся верно. Далее посредством аякса на сервер, банальная проверка:

```
if(isset($_POST['folder'])): echo "Okay";
    else: echo 'No';
    endif;
```

Данные не передаются на сервер. В чём проблема? В JS не сильно силён)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте установить заголовок как в [этом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9713078/1878432) вопросе

```
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

Comment: Установка заголовка помогла. Очень благодарен)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать, что то вроде этого (насколько помню подобное используется в yii2):

```
 public function isAjax()
    {
        return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] === 'XMLHttpRequest';
    }
```